# Background image clipping

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/R82a4/

This is what I tried, although there is no point:

```
<div style="background-position: -50%; width: 100%; background-image: url('/assets/upload/stab/1/taccos.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto; height: 885px; width: 792px;">
sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />
</div>
```

I want the following:

```
|        IMAGE CENTERED         |
|    IMAGE CENTERED     |
|  IMAGE CENTERED   |
| IMAGE CENTERED |
|IMAGE CENTERED|
|MAGE CENTERE|
|AGE CENTER|
|GE CENTE|
```

as the screen becomes thicker, the image should be clipped, not resized, its content should be centered vertically

Comment: use `background-position: center center;` and remove all `background-size` property

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R82a4/1/ it doesnt work :S

Comment: remove width and height

Comment: Won't removing the width and height make the image stretch and scew on zoom/zoom out rather than clip?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R82a4/5/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of background-size, use background-position:center, and get rid of the div width; If there is a fixed Div with, the screen width won't effect it, so how can the image be clipped?

```
<div style="background-position: center; width: 100%; background-image: url('http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJYVbh_I1DDoLLOxTwZPy0LPNxkZJvp1LmRydhdVcO2WifcnKN'); background-repeat: no-repeat; height:183px;">
sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />sdfsf<br />
```

Comment: In case anyone wants to see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/R82a4/4/

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/R82a4/3/

```
background-position: center;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJYVbh_I1DDoLLOxTwZPy0LPNxkZJvp1LmRydhdVcO2WifcnKN');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSZqk.png